# cut/cut down when referring to price

Tags: idioms

"The supermarket cut the price." sounds correct to me.

"The supermarket cut down the price." seems a bit redundant.

Is my interpretation correct or are both acceptable?

Comment: Trees are cut down, not prices!

Comment: ...also, people are being cut down in the prime of their lives.